# Meeting invite emails from employers are being sent to my original email address, not the one in my preferences

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, email

As far as I can recall, I get e-mails sent to the correct place in general, but when an employer sends me a calendar invite, it goes to the email address I used to create this account, not the one in my Stack Overflow preferences.

I have a feeling "sending a calendar invite to a potential employee" has very little to do with Stack Overflow, but it does suggest they can see the original email address when they decide to send me an e-mail instead of the one in my preferences.

Here is the one in my preferences (this is the e-mail that I want to receive the calendar invites):

[image]

I've been clicking around to see if there's any other place to set an email address, but I have been unable to find one.

For what it's worth, I still log in to this account with the original email address using Google OAuth, but I originally created the account via the Stack Overflow "create account" form, using no OAuth provider. Hopefully, this provides some information to troubleshoot.

Comment: Just to check, is there no email address from other sources, like the resume on [Job Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current)?

Comment: @AndrewT. I just checked and my resume has the email I want the invites to be sent to. I can't think of any other places where there would be emails.